# Can we change the default build number in GitHub Workflow?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci-runner

[image: The Build number I'm looking for]

I'm looking to change the default build number generated by github(attached image, highlighted yellow), I want to make it something like(2.2.0-build_number)

I'm using the below code, but doesn't seem to work.

```
 steps:  
    - name: Set version number
      run: |
        $version = "3.2."+(4000+$($Env:GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER))+".0"
        echo $version
        echo "VERSION_NUMBER=$version"
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you can't change that number.

The long answer is GitHub Actions is more then a "build tool", it's a workflow automation tool. Some workflows automate building and deploying software, other workflows mange issues in the repository, while others might manage user access. For those reasons, there is not a concept of "version" or "build number" when it comes to GitHub Actions.

If you are looking for ways to manage versions in your repository, you should look into using tags and releases in GitHub.